# JQuery function to apply to all classes and remove the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code I have `img` elements of class `rembtn`. I want each of those images to have their parent `div` (and all its inner content) destroyed on click. So I have this:

```
$('.rembtn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
});
```

There are no errors being logged to my JavaScript console; however, nothing happens when I click on the images.

Reproduction steps: Open http://jaminweb.com/YoutubePlaylist.html and click on the red X. That is supposed to destroy itself along with the text box to the left.

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: Try `$(this).closest('div').remove();` hopefully you'd at least remove something ?

Comment: Presumably, the parent of those elements is not a div. Please post an example of the HTML here.

Comment: This is again one of these questions that don't contain enough information to solve the problem. Without going to your site and digging into it, it seems impossible to find the source of the problem. Next time, please include all the information in your question. For example, the fact that you are creating `.rembtn` elements dynamically and that the event handler is not called at all when you click on of those elements.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the event handler on the `body` as you are adding elements dynamically, like so:

```
$("body").on("click", ".rembtn", function() {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
});
```

Using `$(".rembtn")` requires the elements to already be on the page at load. In the code example above, the event handler is actually on the `body` and then a click on the specified element will bubble up to that level triggering the function.

For more information, and a more thorough explanation of event delegation, check out this link: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1):

Laymanje's answer is correct, but you may want to consider using

```
$('.rembtn').on('click', function()
{
     $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

using "Closest" instead of "Parent". That way, you can just change your selector if you need to edit your markup, instead of having to count the parents.

Edit: To elaborate, the reason that "Parent" won't work is because the jQuery parent function will only return the direct parent. It doesn't check all ancestors. Closest will go up through the ancestor hierarchy, and remove the first "Div" it finds. You should probably change this to an ID selector, to be safer.

```
$('.rembtn').on('click', function()
{
     $(this).closest('#vidplaydiv').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using $(this).parent().remove(); without the 'div' that tells jQuery you mean it's direct parent. If you need to go more than one level up, you can chain .parent() again.

Examples.

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

or possible

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

depending on your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dynamically creating the elements, try using this instead:

```
$(document).on('click', ".rembtn", function() {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the click event outside of jQuery's document ready listener. See what happens if you instead do

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.rembtn').on('click', function()  {
        jQuery(this).parent().remove();                   
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want each of your rembtn images to delete their div you need to call each() and you have to put this code inside $(document).ready(function()

try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".rembtn").click(function(event) {
$(".rembtn").each(function(element) {
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); // or $(this).parent('div').html();
});
});
```

}

It should work.